# Absolute div within a overflow hidden relative div

Tags: html, css

I have this situation where i have structure like below

```
<div class="red">
   <div class="orange"></div>
</div>
```

And css as below

```
.red{
   height:200px;
   width:200px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position:relative;
   background:red;
 }

.orange{
   right: -50px;
   top: 50px;
   height:100px;
   width:100px; 
   position:absolute;
   background:orange;
 }
```

Problem i'm facing is that i need the `.orange` div to show fully but it shows partially because of the overflow on the `.red` div. And i know i can remove the overflow and it will work but overflow is for another feature that i need and i cannot remove it. Is there any way i can make the `.orange` div fully visible without removing overflow from parent div?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmx1g66z/).

Comment: how about changing it to scroll?

Comment: @JanLeeYu That will break the scroll feature. It has to remain hidden.

Comment: Then why do you wanted to show the `.orange`?

Comment: This works, but I guess is not what you need... ;) -> https://jsfiddle.net/Smartik/rmx1g66z/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Breaking out of overflow:hidden](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/)

> Basically, in order for an absolutely positioned element to appear
>   outside of an element with overflow: hidden, its closest positioned
>   ancestor must also be an ancestor of the element with overflow:
>   hidden.

(edit) By omitting the `position:relative` from the parent, the orange box will be absolutely positioned relative to the `<body>` and can then be repositioned with some script: (or just manually position it)

```
css:
    red{
      height:200px;
      width:200px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background:red;
    }

//script
       var parent = $('.red');
       var inner = $('.orange');
       inner.css({
          left:parent.outerWidth()-inner.outerWidth()/2
```

[see fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rmx1g66z/7/)

Comment: This is a brilliant idea but unfortunately it involves changing html structure.

Comment: fixed, the wrapper isn't necessary here.

Comment: Could you please roll back the answer to the version where it was using the wrapper? I think i can use that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add overflow hidden to pseudo-elements and remove it from `.red` selector. I think it should do the trick:

```
.red{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
  background:red;
}
.red:before,
.red:after{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.orange{
  right: -50px;
  top: 50px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px; 
  position:absolute;
  background:orange;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Smartik/rmx1g66z/6/

Comment: This is neat. But apparently there still needs to be `overflow:hidden` present on the `.red` itself.

Comment: It tried and it works but it still breaks scroll feature for main container.

Comment: Then I think the only option you have, is javascript.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly solution

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .container{
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .red {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        background: red;
    }
    .orange {
        right: -50px;
        top: 50px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        background: orange;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any context of your overflow problem affecting other things, could you use specific overflow-x and overflow-y properties?

i.e.

```
.red {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try with below code it may help you

```css
.red{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
  background:red;
}
.orange{
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%; 
  position:absolute;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"><div class="orange"></div></div>
```